# Conflict between on click event and setting focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to conform to an accessibility request to set the focus on a modal when it is open. On the on click event for the link that opens the modal, I am try to set the focus to a link element within the modal (the modal exists when the entire page loads, it's just not visible; also the link element in the modal has an href value). However I can't seem to modify the focus. I can do it in a document keydown event, which makes me think that there is some conflict with the on click. Is there any known conflict with setting the focus away from something that's just been clicked? Is there any workaround?

Link on main page:

```
<li id="country-selector" class="country-selector">
    <a alt="Country Selector" href="#"><img src="../assets/images/countries/nz.png" alt="New Zealand flag"> New Zealand</a
</li>
```

Link on modal (using Handlebars; not sure if relevant but including anyway):

```
<li class="cs-region {{#if @first}}active{{/if}}">
    <a href="#cs-{{slug}}" class="cs-tabs__link" {{#if @first}}id="cs-countries__first-focus" {{/if}}>{{region}}</a>
</li>
```

Which comes out as:

```
<li class="cs-region active">
    <a href="#cs-europe" class="cs-tabs__link" id="cs-countries__first-focus">Europe</a>
</li>
```

for the first link.

Here's my JS:

```
$('#country-selector').on('click', function(e) {
    //Accessibility; make the modal keyboard navigable
    var modalParent = document.getElementById('cs-countries');

    if ($.contains(modalParent, document.activeElement) !== true) {
        //tabbed outside modal, so reset focus
        console.log("activeElement is outside modal: ", document.activeElement);
        document.getElementById('cs-countries__first-focus').focus(); //native js method
        $('#cs-countries__first-focus').focus(); //jquery method
        console.log("after set: ", document.activeElement);
    } else {
        console.log("activeElement is inside modal: ", document.activeElement);
    }
});
```

Neither jQuery or native JS methods work, though I've used them elsewhere on the project for a similar issue, but just not on an on click event. It is possible to tab to the modal after tabbing through the rest of the main page elements, and I can set the focus when tabbing, but I need the focus to start on an element inside the modal.

Comment: A side question: What do you want achive with the first if query? In my eyes `== false` and `!= true` does the same. Or I am wrong?

Comment: I guess it's just a personal habit? I tend to write everything in terms of truth. It's less mental gymnastics and I make fewer errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using setTimeout (and breaking for lunch):

```
$('#country-selector').on('click', function(e) {
    //Accessibility; make the modal keyboard navigable
    var modalParent = document.getElementById('cs-countries');

    if ($.contains(modalParent, document.activeElement) !== true) {
        //tabbed outside modal, so reset focus
        console.log("activeElement is outside modal: ", document.activeElement);
        setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("in set timeout");
                $('#cs-countries__first-focus').focus();
                console.log("afterset: ", document.activeElement);
            }, 1);
    } else {
        console.log("activeElement is inside modal: ", document.activeElement);
    }
});
```